# Conservation of Energy in Fluid Mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation

While deriving the Conservation of Energy equation for Fluids using First Law of Thermodynamics in a Lagrangian Co-ordinate, there comes a point where the Work done by Surface forces are converted to volume integrals using Gauss' Theorem. The author mentions it as a step to exploit arbitrariness of volume V considered. My question is the same arbitrariness holds true for the Surface as well, then why we need to convert Surface Integral to Volume Integral?

What am i missing, can anyone please help?

Comment: You are trying to express the energy balance in differential form, so all the differential terms need to be expressed in terms of volume integrals so that the integrands can be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Agreed. So it doesn't have to do anything with arbitrariness of Volume, right?

Comment: If I understand you original question correctly, then yes.